# Task-dependent "reversed" handedness: why use left hand for some tasks? How is it controlled by the brain?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, physiology, muscles

I am right-handed. Which means that when I hammer down a nail, I hold the nail in my left hand, with which I can hold it straight and at a controlled position.

This is true in situations where the task of holding something in place is  simultaneous with a more complex task, such has hammering, done with the right hand. But I note that even when there is no other task, I personally use my left hand to hold in place, e.g., a  bottle that I am filling up in a stream of water.

To generalize a little, it seems to me that while I use my right hand for precise motion or applying a force, I'll use my left hand to maintain a position against forces.

Is this behaviour something documented? Does one develop specific brain control to implement this controlled-position tasks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dynamic-dominance hypothesis of handedness states that the essential factor that distinguishes dominant from nondominant arm performance is the facility governing the control of limb dynamics. Sainburg ([1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11807578)) writes that

> It should be noted that dominant arm advantages do not apply to all
>   tasks, or all aspects of tasks. Healey et al. (1986) examined an
>   extensive range of tasks and found that four factors or groups of
>   tasks accounted for 80% of the variance in hand preference among the
>   110 subjects tested. Tasks that were almost exclusively associated
>   with dominant arm use included activities requiring precision in
>   interjoint coordination and trajectory formation. (...) In contrast,
>   tasks that involved spatially orienting a body segment posture were
>   more often performed with the nondominant arm. These tasks included
>   posturing the hand to point toward a distant object, which is similar
>   to other functional tasks such as holding a piece of paper that is
>   being cut with scissors, or orienting the hand in space for catching a
>   baseball. Such postural orientation tasks are less dependent on
>   intersegmental dynamics, since the trajectory used to attain the
>   posture is not critical for task success. The dynamic dominance
>   hypothesis thus appears to account for the extent to which hand
>   preferences for specific activities are lateralized.

This appears to be consistent with your experience.